# Can't convert NonType to String error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I have a small piece of Python code which uses formatting and does not behave as expected.

Here is the code:

[image: TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly]

As you can see, I check the type of x and it is a float.  I didn't check y in this version, but I have checked and it is a float as well. float as well.

Yet when I do to print them with formatting, Python complains that it can't convert NoneType to string. And, even if I put str() around each format invocation, it still doesn't see all the objects passed to print() as strings.

Shouldn't the formatting take two floats and deliver a (formatted) string?

Comment: Can you post your code in the question using tick marks (`\`\`\`code\`\`\``) instead of as an image?

Comment: not really, as I need to capture the output as well.

Comment: The 2nd *print* has nothing to do there.

Comment: stupid error on my part.  But do you truly need to wrap results from format() with an str() call?  It seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake may be that additional `print("{:.4f}").format(y)`
Try replacing it with something like:
`print("{:.4f}".format(x) + " " + "{:.4f}".format(y))`

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Functions - **print**(**objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) syntax. The 2<sup>nd</sup> one shouldn't be there - as *print* doesn't return anything (or returns *None*).

You wanted the line to be:

```py
print("{:.4f}    {:.4f}".format(x, y))
```